# Extrapolate $y^2=4x^2-4x^4$ from plot

Tags: conic-sections, curves, extrapolation

I am trying to extrapolate a function based on the distribution of eigenvalues of certain matrices I am working with.

In a simple case I successfully described the data with the function $y^2=4x^2-4x^4$:

[image]

However when I consider more extreme cases my equations become very tedious to solve. I \underline{know} the shape is very similar to $y^2=4x^2-4x^4$, but I need the two 'wings' to be further apart without altering their height:

[image]
OR maybe
[image]

Note that they should $\textit{not}$ be perfect ellipses, otherwise the following equation would make the trick:
$$
\frac{1}{\frac{(x-a)^2}{\tau}+\frac{y^2}{\tau}}+\frac{1}{\frac{(x-b)^2}{\tau}+\frac{y^2}{\tau}}=1
$$

What should I change in the following equation in order to increase the distance between the two wings without affecting their height:

$$
y^2=4x^2-4x^4
$$

I tried to add different coefficients here and there but I do not manage to develop the intuition on what to change. I am almost there!

Any observation or help is always appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:
based on the comments, it works indeed! now I simply need to know how to properly scale.
[image]

Comment: What do you think of the following:  $$y^2=4(x^2-4)-4(x^2-4)^2$$

Comment: Whoah, not bad.. It works for the points $-2$ and $2$. Nice intuition! I simply need to scale the shape and it works. Well done! Thanks a lot.